# Java Error Cannot be aplied to

Tags: java

I get the following error:

> Message(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
>   in Guardar cannot be applied to
>   (javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)

This is my function:

```
public void Message(HttpServletResponse response, String message, String       FechaCompleta) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    out.println("<head>");
    out.println("</head>");
    out.println("<body bgcolor=\"white\">");
    out.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"calendarioModificar.js\"></script>");
    out.println("<table border=0>");
    out.println("<tr><td><h1>Atencion!</h1></td></tr>");
    out.println("<tr><td>"+message+ "</td></tr>");
    out.println("<tr><td>La fecha: "+FechaCompleta+" tiene demasiados pedidos. Sentimos las molestias.</td></tr>");
    out.println("<form action=\"Modificar\" method=\"GET\">");
    out.println("<tr><td><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Modificar\"></td></form><td><a href=\"Fin.html\"><button>Continuar</button></a></td></tr>");
    }
```

I call it this way:

```
if (Verification(SQLcount) == true){
    Message(response, "Ya no puedes reservar este dia", FechaCompleta, Hora);
} else {
}
```

What is the error?

Comment: you are passing 4 parameters but your actual method has nly 3 parameters

Comment: Please remove the void in front of Message if you intend this to be a constructor or change the name of the method to conform with Java coding standards.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing 1 more parameter than method needs.

You must remove one of "Ya no puedes reservar ese día", FechaCompleta or Hora, or add another String parameter into method declaration:

```
public void Message(HttpServletResponse response, String message, String       FechaCompleta, String Hora) throws IOException
```